# DC3/Skew Suffix Array Algorithm doesn't work for specific cases

Tags: algorithms, strings, substrings, suffix-array

When applying the DC3/Skew algorithm to the string **yabadabado**, I can't quite get it to sort correctly. This issue happens in other cases, but this is a short example to show it.

This first table is for reference:
[image]

These are the triples of R<sub>12</sub>

[image]

We have a tie between `i = 1`, and `i = 5` since both their triples are `aba`.

We now need to get the suffix array of the ranks `R'` through recursing, but we can quickly break this tie since `i_1 = [1,3] > i_5 = [1,2]` which implies that the suffix starting at i = 5 should come before i = 1. Recursing returns the same result with R'<sub>5</sub> < R'<sub>1</sub>.

So applying these results puts the relative order of those two suffixes as:

```
S[5,] == abado // Comes first (smaller)
S[1,] == abadabado
```

But `abadabado < abado`. I've been looking at this for a while, and can't seem to figure out where I stray from the algorithm.

I'm hoping someone with more experience using the algorithm can point me in the right direction.

Comment: $R$ in the paper "Linear Work Suffix Array Construction" refers to the concatenation of $R_1$ and $R_2$: `[abb][ada][bba][do$][bba][dab][bad][o$$]`, this is different from your $R_{12}$. Are you referring to a different algorithm?

Comment: No you're absolutely right, and fixing that fixes my issue. Thanks a lot for pointing it out.